# ExpectedException.expectMessage((String) null) is not working

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am writing JUnit4 unit tests and have a condition where I need to assert that an exception was thrown with `null` message.

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public final void testNullException() throws Exception {
    exception.expect(Exception.class);
    exception.expectMessage((String) null);
    mPackage.getInfo(null);
}
```

The line `mPackage.getInfo(null)` is throwing an Exception with `null` message properly, but the JUnit test is failing with the message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (an instance of java.lang.Exception and exception with message a string containing null)
     but: exception with message a string containing null message was null
```

Is there anyway to test for an exception with a `null` message in **JUnit4 way**. (I know I can catch the exception and check for the conditions myself).

Comment: `expectMessage(Matcher<String> matcher)` should do it with a `isNull` matcher.

Comment: Using Matcher worked... Thanks...

Comment: Could you show the syntax that works?

Comment: @JimFlood, added it as an answer.

Comment: @Codebender thx. I found this works, too: exception.expectMessage(nullValue(String.class)); -- from org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.nullValue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `org.hamcrest.Matcher` with `org.hamcrest.core.IsNull` worked for me.

The syntax is,

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public final void testNullException() throws Exception {
    exception.expect(Exception.class);
    Matcher<String> nullMatcher = new IsNull<>();
    exception.expectMessage(nullMatcher);
    mPackage.getInfo(null);
}
```